# Debut Episodes of Rival Characters in Detective Conan (Case Closed)?

Tags: detective-conan

I used to watch Detective Conan when I was younger and remember I got through the first 100 or so episodes. The most prominent "rivals" of Conan from what I remember was Kaitou Kid and Heiji Hattori. Who are some other characters that come later in the series and which episodes do they first appear?

Answer (score 1):

Kaitou Kid isn't really a rival character, he's somewhat of an antagonist.

Other than Heiji, there's only Sera Masumi who is a recurring character and a detective.
She first appears in episode 646.